# Register to register comparisons

Tags: comparison, instruction-set

I have studied what composes a CPU and how random access memory is structured, but I don't understand register to register comparison operations.

"Why are register to register comparison operations usually faster than the equivalent operation on two data entries in RAM?"

Answer (score 0):

RAM access, when it is outside of the cache, is very slow. To access the data on your DDR3 module is several hundred times slower than accessing registers (or even L1 cache). Today's desktop (or server, or laptop) processors lose most of their time to access data outside of their (L1) cache, e.g. on the DDR3 RAM modules.

To put figures in perspective: accessing a register or a L1 cached data takes a few cycles at most (so, on a 3GHz machine that means one nanosecond typically). Acessing data on your DDR3 RAM modules takes about 200 or 300 nanoseconds. During all that time, your processor could execute more than a hundred machine instructions.

This is why data locality is increasingly important. And it has consequences even on the code we are writing: scanning a linked list may be a lot slower than scanning an array.

The details are hard: it is very difficult to predict the worst case execution time of a small routine on current processors.